# Google Knowledge Graph API post retrieves part or no Knowledge Card information

Tags: google-knowledge-graph

Google Knowledge Graph API post retrieves part or no Knowledge Card information 
For eg: Query: Pradhan Mantri Jan Dhan Yojana 
does not provide information about the queried scheme. Information about other similar scheme is supplementary as per knowledge graph.

Also if the query is asked in a different way removing space 
for eg: Query: PradhanMantri JanDhan Yojana
returns items of zero list. Like in Google it prompts do you mean this ....  would have been a good feature.

Also for the query for eg: Query: Narendra Modi
doesnt provide the below information available on knowledge card

Born: 17 September 1950 (age 68 years), Vadnagar
Full name: Narendra Damodardas Modi
Spouse: Jashodaben Narendrabhai Modi (m. 1968)
Education: Gujarat University (1983), University of Delhi (1978), Mooljee Jetha College, Jalgaon, School of Open Learning
Parents: Heeraben Modi, Damodardas Mulchand Mod

Is this the expected behavior and if so how could we use the API to retrieve he full knowledge card information